How long does the temp HP from the Inspiring Leader feat last, and how often can the character with the feat give a speech?
I understand that each individual creature/ally can gain the temporary HP from the Inspiring Leader feat once per short or long rest, but I have some questions:

How long does the temp HP granted by the inspiring speech last (i.e. for the rest of the game day, or x hrs)?
Also, how often can the character with the feat give a speech? For example, can the leader use their inspiring speech on a party of 6 people, then if someone summons a bunch of animal companions, can the leader then immediately give another speech to then give that new set of allies temp hp as well? (Although as it's a 10-minute speech, I doubt it'll be done mid-combat and therefore measured in rounds, unless used in conjunction with tiny hut for protection.)


Arguable whether someone's animal companion can "understand you", which is a requisite for being inspired.  At the very least I would think they would need to understand the language in which you are speaking.

@kirt luckily my character also knows speak with animals

The temporary hit points “last until they’re depleted or you finish a long rest.”
The rules for temporary hit points state:

Unless a feature that grants you temporary hit points has a duration, they last until they're depleted or you finish a long rest.

No duration is stated in the feat description.
You can give the speech as often as you like.
If there was a limit to how often you could make the speech, the feat description would say so. It doesn’t say so.

Buuuuut, you can only benefit from one speech at a time

Yes, but it is still useful to be able to give multiple speeches - for example if you have a larger party with lots of henchmen, you can first pep talk the main team, and then give anohter speech to the next group.

@NobodytheHobgoblinthats what I was looking for our druid is a close friend( to the point where regular bouts of messing with each other is common) and I'm looking to see if I can really frustrate him by giving inspiring speech temp HP to the main group anbd then wait until he casts Conjure Animals and then buff them as well and then watch as he has to tracvk the HP and tempHP of each of the animals he conjures.( as well as his own. hp and temp hp.

@MattBartlett Arguable whether the animals conjured by the druid would understand the speech giver, which is a requisite for being inspired. At the very least I would think they would need to understand the language in which you are speaking.
